# @POST in RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have been trying to understand @POST in RESTful web service using Jersey. I have gone through http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html for the same and was able to get some information about @POST, but felt confusing and clumpsy. Can anyone explain @POST with a simple example or share links about the same.

Implementing @POST through TODO objects in above link was fine but i wish to learn @POST through some other simple example so that i can go ahead to develop my own complex @POST examples.

Help will be appreciable,
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) to get a more fundamental understanding of the process?

Comment: Thanks dude...it was really helpful to understand the topic. It would be very helpful if you share some information on Security of RESTful web services. I would like to create secure web services. Any link or tutorials which will deliver the required information clearly..??

Comment: check this link
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html.
It has a clear explanation about restful web services

Answer (score 25):

Please find example below, it might help you

```
package jersey.rest.test;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HEAD;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class SimpleService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "Get:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response postMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "POST:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    //@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public Response postStrMsg( String msg) {
        String output = "POST:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response putMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "PUT: Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response deleteMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "DELETE:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @HEAD
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response headMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "HEAD:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

for testing you can use any tool like RestClient (http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)

Answer (score 22):

REST webservice: (http://localhost:8080/your-app/rest/data/post)

```
package com.yourorg.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @Path("/data")
public class JSONService {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createDataInJSON(String data) { 

        String result = "Data post: "+data;

        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build(); 
    }
```

Client send a post:

```
package com.yourorg.client;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/your-app/rest/data/post");

        String input = "{\"message\":\"Hello\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jose, it was really good and helpful. Can you please provide me sample code with DELETE and PUT annotations. So that i can go ahead in creating some more complex code. Thanks

Comment: This just saved the day for me, I was having the hardest time getting my post request to work with json. Thanks!